# ListView with backward forward navigation and limited elements

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

In Sencha, how to create a `DataView` or `List` component which renders only 1 item at a time and contains `prev/next` buttons to navigate data?
Store has pagination enabled to pull only 5 records at a time. Out of these 5 records I want to display only 1 record at a time on the view and with navigation buttons to move forward/backwards. Is there a built-in component for this requirement?
I see few SO posts ([Sencha Touch limit number of items in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18573068/sencha-touch-limit-number-of-items-in-list)) suggesting to use 2 stores (DisplayStore to slice the actual data). This didn't work for me. I tested this with static data in the actual store. It still renders all the data in the list. Moreover I am looking for forward/backward navigation buttons too.

If there is no such built-in component (at least close enough), I want to create one for my needs. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You should go with a filter, and two buttons.
The handler for the next button could be alike

```
var number= list.getStore().first().getId()
list.filter('id', number+1)
```

If there is anyway to increase a number for the next valid item. Otherwise you need a counter of your current selected item and increase that.